# Bind arguments to function in two steps in c++?

Tags: c++, boost

I have a class Manager and a class Base (with subclasses deriving from Base, say A : public Base). Inside Manager I create the right subclass of Base but then Base is oblivious to the existence of Manager. I wanted to pass into this created subclass of Base a function object bound to a member method of the Manager class for the A object to invoke. In other words during creation it would be something like this:

```
void Manager::createThing()
{
FunctionObject func;
if (doExtraWork)
    func.bind(&Manager::someMethod, this);

Base *bla = new A(func);
}
```

Then inside of A, I would like to be able to detect whether we have extra work to have the Manager carry on us and do so, something like:

```
A::update()
{
 if (func) //ideally detect if func was bound to someMethod or func is empty
    func(this); //equivalent to the above instance of manager calling someMethod on this instance of A

//do regular stuff after;
}
```

How can I go about doing this (probably with boost function or something like that)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `FunctionObject` type is `boost::function<void()>`, then you can assign to this from the result of `boost::bind`, something like this:

```
boost::function<void()> f = boost::bind(&Manager::someMethod, this);
Base *b = new A(f);
```

where the constructor of A has signature `A(boost::function<void()>)`. Calling a `boost::function` has slightly more overhead than a virtual function call.

I don't know enough about your particular situation to know for sure, but you might end up with a better interface if you actually define an abstract base class representing the functionality of f, and have your constructor for `Base` and `A` take an object of the abstract base class instead, like this:-

```
struct ThingDoer
{
    virtual void do() = 0;
};

class Manager : private ThingDoer
{
    virtual void do()
    { ... }

    void createThing()
    {
        Base *b = new A(this);
    }
};
```

where the constructor of A has signature `A(ThingDoer*)`.

If you've previously read about the 'delegate' design pattern, you know the kind of thing I mean. In this simple, abstract example, it just looks clunkier and longer than the solution using `boost::function`, but it does have potential advantages for real software:

- It lets you give names to the 'delegate' type `ThingDoer`, your implementation of that type, and the function inside it. Also, if you use Doxygen or some other structured comment system, it's a lot easier to document the delegate class than a function object parameter.
- It lets you choose in the `Manager` class and any derived classes whether to inherit from `ThingDoer`, or have a nested (private or protected) class that inherits ThingDoer.
- If you want to add an extra function to the interface later (to make it do two different things), it's easier to do that, and you won't be tempted to simply add more and more function objects. (But it's only easier later because you've already paid the extra cost of writing your code this way.)
- If you have programmers from the Java or C# communities, they'll probably be more familiar with code like this.

It may be that none of those are advantages in your situation, in which case, definitely use the `boost::function` / `boost::bind` solution. I've done the same in similar situations. I probably ought to mention too that C++11 has most or all of the function-binding functionality in `std::` itself.

Comment: thanks awesome response...I'll think about the delegate thing..as for the bind way..is there a way for the conditional inside of A::update() to detect that it's boost::bind has been bound or not? It would be nicer than passing a pointer to a boost::function which could be null (as I would have to use new) or a dummy noop method in Manager bound to the boost::function...

Comment: When you evaluate a `boost::function` as a bool, it is true iff it has been set to some function. That is, `if (f) f();` works the way you want.